# MAX487 can transmit but won't receive

Tags: uart, differential, rs485

I am trying to use a MAX487 chip to convert a regular UART signal to half-duplex RS485 signal and vice versa. I am using Atmega328PB as my micro controller. My circuit has no problem with transmission, but it won't receive anything I send from my terminal software. I used my oscilloscope to check out the signal, and I noticed that the signal amplitude is very different when the micro controller transmits the signal versus when the terminal software transmits the signal. Here are my circuit diagram and screenshots.

During transmission, the Atmega328PB's TX enable and the MAX487 Driver Enable pin were set to high, and the RX enable and RX complete interrupt enable were set to low.

During receive, the Atmega328PB's RX enable and RX complete interrupt enable were set to high, and the TX enable and the MAX487 Driver Enable pin were set to low

Circuit Diagram:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Differential signal between pin A and B, referenced at pin B, PC -> microcontroller (RX):

[image: uC MAX487 RX]

Differential signal between pin A and B, referenced at pin B, microcontroller -> PC (TX):

[image: uC MAX487 TX]

I tried probing A and B at a time while referencing the ground, and the same thing happened. When uC -> PC, the signal swing between 0 and 1 was 5V, while when PC -> uC, the signal swing between 0 and 1 was approximately 1V.

If anyone has seen this happening before, or knows how to solve this issue, could you please help me?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is your microcontroller disabling the driver to actually be able to receive anything? Or are you just leaving the driver enabled the entire time?

Comment: @DKNguyen The driver is disabled the entire time, except when the microcontroller is transmitting data. Once data transmission is finished, the microcontroller pulls the DE pin low again. I will add that information in my post.

Comment: What line driver does your PC use? You've only shown us the circuit for the microcontroller end of the link.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for pointing that out! I am using a Uotek UT-890A USB to RS485/422 converter cable. The converter circuit uses SP485 transceiver chips, and there are two 4.7 kOhm resistors, one pulling A line up to 5V and the other one pulling B line down to the ground. It appears that there's no load resister in between A and B.

Comment: You seem to be biasing the bus from both sides. Have you tried removing the biasing resistors on the microcontroller's side (the 500 R on the A/B lines)?

Comment: @MarcosG. I tried doing that just now, and still no luck.

Comment: I see. This kind of thing is always more obvious than it seems. I think you should try to isolate the problem. Can you be absolutely sure the USB to RS485 works and it's properly wired (T/R+ pin 1 on your cable should go to **B**, or maybe to A, there is a lot of confusion on that depending on the manufacturer)? You can also try to monitor DE/~RE with a second channel on the scope at the same time, see the screenshot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036578/pymodbus-read-input-register-of-energy-meter-over-rs485-on-uart-of-raspberry-p/56106253#56106253).

Comment: And the last thing that comes to mind: are you powering anything from batteries? If so you might need to add a GND wire to join all grounds together. An offtopic note: that Tek scope brings good memories from way back. I think it was the first digital one I handled, I can still remember the excitement of the magic Autoset...

Comment: Now, last thing for real: don't make any assumptions and try to isolate everything. Even if one side of the transmission is working, try to check your USB cable with some other device if you have it, try to make it work half duplex from both sides. And if you have more MAX487 ICs, just replace the one you are using, it's not that easy to brick them but it's not unheard of. Last time I ordered 10 to have spares! Good luck.

Comment: @MarcosG. I went back to my schematic to see what could've have possibly gone wrong. It turned out that I was using SPI1 without MISO1 pin, and I used that pin to enable the MAX487 chip. Enabling SPI1 automatically set the MISO1 pin as an input, putting it in high impedance state and that's why the MAX487 had an erratic behavior. I feel dumb, but a lesson learned. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: As I said: it's always more obvious than it seems. Have fun with your bus!